# Counting the number of references to a label

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it possible to retrieve the number of references to a label?

For example, can I colour theorems that are referenced using `\ref` more than 5 times red?

I did not find informations about this kind of mechanism elsewhere on the internet and on this site.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} \label{tm:1}
    Some theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} \label{tm:2}
    Some other theorem
\end{theorem}

\ref{tm:1}\ref{tm:1}\ref{tm:1}\ref{tm:1}\ref{tm:1}\ref{tm:1}
\ref{tm:2}\ref{tm:2}\ref{tm:2}

\end{document}
```

In this case, the first theorem should be red and the second should remain untouched (black).

Edit: Sorry I did not make the question clear. The name of the theorem should be coloured, not the references.

Comment: Is this a rule for all references then?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer If it is possible this effect should be restricted to only theorems.

Comment: Well, if you're fine with some `\theoref{...}` wrapper instead of `\ref{...}` it would be easier

Comment: Shall the theorem ref. be displayed in red colour counted the 5th reference  and for the rest of the document or right from the start (that would be definitely more complex)

Comment: is what you want to highlight in red the references to the "+5" theorem, or the theorem (header) itself ... or both?  if the theorem itself, then something must be written into the `.aux` file, and applied in a second pass.  (@ChristianHupfer's answer makes a good start for the counting.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks ... I just don't have time to improve it right now... my idea was to use the `.aux` file for it already, but, as said, no time...

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry I did not make the question clear. The theorem being referenced should be coloured, not the `\ref`s.

Comment: @HenryW.: What? All work useless :-(

Answer (score 2):

This tracks the number of references to a theorem label by using a wrapper command `\theoref` and displays the colour accordingly. However, the first 4 references will be left blue (for example) while the next ones are red (for example), i.e. the tracking does not know how many references to the same label are done in total right from the start of the document. This would be next step of improving.

The labels are stored in `expl3` `\prop` - list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}



\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\specialrefdisplaycolor}{red}
\newcommand{\usualrefdisplaycolor}{blue}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@ref\ref

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_set:Nn {Nx}

\prop_new:N \l_henry_label_prop 

\NewDocumentCommand{\theoref}{O{5}m}{%
  \prop_if_in:NnTF \l_henry_label_prop {#2} {
    \int_set:Nx \l_tmpa_int {\prop_item:Nn \l_henry_label_prop {#2}}
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int 
    \prop_put:NnV \l_henry_label_prop {#2} \l_tmpa_int
  }{% End of T - Branch
    \prop_put:NnV \l_henry_label_prop {#2} {\c_one}
    \int_set:Nx \l_tmpa_int {\prop_item:Nn \l_henry_label_prop {#2}}
  }
  \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int} < {#1} {%
    \group_begin:
    \color{\usualrefdisplaycolor}\latex@@ref{#2}%
    \group_end:

  }{
    \group_begin:
    \color{\specialrefdisplaycolor}\latex@@ref{#2}
    \group_end:
  } 
}
\makeatother



\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} \label{tm:1}
    Some theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} \label{tm:2}
    Some other theorem
\end{theorem}

In Theorem \theoref{tm:1}

\theoref{tm:1}

\theoref{tm:1} 

\theoref{tm:1} 

\theoref{tm:1} 

\theoref{tm:1} 

\theoref{tm:1}

\theoref{tm:2} 

\theoref{tm:2} 

\theoref{tm:2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of displaying the importance of a theorem, and every other labeled thing, is to try my beta version of `trackRefs.sty`: it does the following: At every `\label`, prints pages at which the label is referenced via `\ref`, `\eqref`, or `\autoref`. One option "disable" which omits the package, but defines the commands that might still be in auxiliary files Download the LaTeX style file, beta version, from http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/anthony.roberts/LaTeX/trackRefs.sty

However, does not work (yet?) with sophisticated packages such as `cleveref`.